# AWS list instances that are pending and running with one CLI call

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an application which needs to know how many EC2 instances I have in both the `pending` and `running` states. I could run the two following commands and sum them to get the result, but that means my `awscli` will be making two requests, which is both slow and probably bad practice.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values="running" \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' \
    --output text \
    | wc -l


aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values="pending" \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' \
    --output text \
    | wc -l
```

Is there a way of combining these two queries into a single one, or another way of getting the total `pending` + `running` instances using a single query?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shorthand syntax](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options) with commas:

```
Values=running,pending
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add several filter values as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running,pending" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' \
--output text \
| wc -l
```